# How to open an additional hyperlink (word document on local intranet) and bring it to front?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, hyperlink, intranet

I have excel sheet with hyperlinks to my local intranet network files.

The address of hyperlinks is like this:  `http://maxapp.local:90/allhelipa.doc`

**The problem:**

If there is already an opened word document and then I clicked hyperlink (Word Document on my local intranet),
The later file is not opened automatically and I have to click on the flashing taskbar button to open the cited second file.

This issue occurs only with Microsoft word documents found on my local intranet.

If there no open document and I clicked on any word hyperlink, It opens normally without any issue.

I tried to put the same word documents on my work **shared folder** and set hyperlinks address to the respective location.

There is no issue to open an additional hyperlink (Word Document) and it brought to front automatically without I have to click on the flashing taskbar button.

Is there any option to apply or any registry setting to use?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your problem (Office 365), so I cannot test the solution I propose...

Please, use this event in Word `normal.dotm`, if your problem is related to Word documents type:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    If Application.Documents.Count > 1 Then
        AppActivate Application.ActiveWindow.Caption
    End If
End Sub
```

Theoretically, it should activate Word application when a document is open.

If it does not work in that way, API call (probably, `SetForegroundWindow`) should make the job. I tried avoiding API, if this simple solution works for you...

I tested it from Excel, using the next code:

```
Sub testActivateWord()
    Dim objWd As Object
    Set objWd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    AppActivate objWd.ActiveWindow.Caption
    Set objWd = Nothing
End Sub
```

and it does the job...

It needs error handling for the case of no Word session already open, but this is simple. I mean, in Excel. I Word, `Application` is `Application` for all cases. :)

Comment: I tried the first solution, But I got (Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument) at this line `AppActivate Application.ActiveWindow.Caption`,
I have put the code on **Normal--->ThisDocument**, I am using office 2016.

Comment: @Waleed If no Word session open, no `ActiveWindow` exists... Please, try the updated code. It previously check if there are more than 1 document (normal.dotm should be the first...). If it still does not work, may I connect trough AnyDesk? I cannot test it on my environment...

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Unfortunately IT on my work is very restricted and they will not allow this kind of connection.

Comment: Beside your first option (after update) ,also I added your second code to my excel workbook on `FollowHyperlink` event, then **sometimes** no issue to open multi hyperlinks and sometimes the issue as it is.

Comment: Also, I remembered that, there was a security warning if I opened any word file from my local intranet,
I have used a `registry setting` to suppress this message , I applied this setting from a long time ago (Up voted for your help)

Comment: I found that I have to interact with previous already opened window (MS Word ) just like click on it.
I think using API is a must, in that case, I will open a new question on ST (as it is now a programming issue).
Please, do you are still interested to help?

Comment: I do not know wat's really happening... If the (Word) window is activated for a moment and then the caller (EXCEL) take focus, such an approach should be done in Excel. If not, the above suggested way should work, I think. `Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "User32" _
                                                 (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr` And it should be called as `SetForegroundWindow CLngPtr(Application.ActiveWindow.Hwnd)` from inside application. But in such a case is should work using `AppActivate`, too. Not having a test environment, I don't know why.

Comment: I have post my question on St , Please watch the short video to fully understand the problem, could you help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75130612/bring-previous-opened-window-word-document-to-foreground